# Valid DateTime not being accepted by MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to scrape and show blog posts onto my website with PHP and am storing them into a MySQL database. certain timestamps for their creation are not being accepted and these timestamps are valid. Such as "2019-03-31 01:01:00"

Tried to reformat the timestamp but still same error.

The raw timestamp is "31/03" and I did this for convert:

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($timestamp));
```

Before inserting it

It gets defaulted with error:

```
Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2019-03-31 01:01:00' for column 'post_date'
```

Comment: `echo $datetime;`

Comment: and also please `echo $timestamp;`

Comment: And what´s the type of post_date in your table??

Comment: ```$datetime = 2019-03-31 01:01:00 AND $timestamp = 31/03 01:01:00```

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: @nacho Sorry I wrote datetime, the column type is timestamp

Comment: @P.Salmon it is all in UTC

Comment: Do you get this error if you attempt to insert with a hardcoded value of '2019-03-31 01:01:00'?

Comment: Double-check the time zone for both the system and mysql. March 31st is the DST start date for many countries (52 according to https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2019.html), which makes 1:01 invalid

Comment: @PatrickQ No and it is only happening on this timestamp

Comment: Could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437250/sqlstate22007-invalid-datetime-format-1292-incorrect-datetime-value-2019-0 but I;m not sure how appropriate the answer is.

Comment: @aynber is right. You can try with this timestamps to see **'2019-03-31 00:01:00', '2019-03-31 02:01:00', '2019-03-31 03:01:00'. '2019-03-31 04:01:00'** The only period it is not valid it is from 01:00 to 01:59

Comment: To see the timezones within mysql, do `show variables like '%time_zone%';`

Comment: @aynber You're probably correct, but what's odd is OP claims that the error doesn't occur when hardcoding the '2019-03-31 01:01:00' string into the query.

Comment: @PatrickQ True, but it also happens with only this timestamp. So hard to tell without knowing more.

Comment: @P.Salmon Seems it was the timezone, I had no idea about this, thank you so much it was driving me crazy!